# Pandas: i)groupby col_a ii) sort by col_b iii)sort df by col_b min value for each group

Tags: python, pandas

given a dataframe:

```
  col_a      col_b
0     b 2022-01-01
1     a 2022-01-02
2     c 2022-10-03
3     b 2022-10-01
4     a 2022-10-03
5     c 2022-10-02
```

I want to:

- groupby col_a
- within groups, values are sorted by col_b
- the groups are then sorted by order of min of col_b

so the first row should correspond to the col_a group that has had the first value in col_b.

desired output:

```py
  col_a      col_b
0     b 2022-01-01 # b has first min value  col_b --> at the start of df 
1     b 2022-10-01 # the next value is the sorted next value of group b. 
2     a 2022-01-02 # a has second min value col_b --> second in df order 
3     a 2022-10-03
4     c 2022-10-03 
5     c 2022-10-02
```

I am able to group by col_a, and within group sort by col_b, but I am not able to then order the df by the min value of col_b for each group

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col_a": ['b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c'],
    'col_b' :   pd.to_datetime(["2022/01/01","2022/01/02","2022/10/03","2022/10/01", "2022/10/03","2022/10/02"])
})


desired_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col_a": ['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'],
    'col_b' :  pd.to_datetime(["2022/01/01", "2022/10/01","2022/01/02", "2022/10/03","2022/10/03", "2022/10/02"])
})

print (df.groupby('col_a').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('col_b'))) # this is not working
```

Comment: You have to refine your problem down to the one thing you need to know to solve whatever problem you have. This question comes off as "do my homework pls". Usually, by trying to ask the right question you might end up finding that it has already been asked. More importantly, the title of your question is undecipherable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary column with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
out = (df
   .assign(key=df.groupby('col_a')['col_b'].transform('min'))
   .sort_values(by=['key', 'col_a', 'col_b'])
   .drop(columns='key')
)
```

Or [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['col_b'], df['col_a'],
                          df.groupby('col_a')['col_b'].transform('min')])]
```

Output:

```
  col_a      col_b
0     b 2022-01-01
3     b 2022-10-01
1     a 2022-01-02
4     a 2022-10-03
5     c 2022-10-02
2     c 2022-10-03
```